# Filter lists from list of lists whose sum equal to 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm pretty noob in Python. I've list of list like this around 50 or 60 sub-lists (is that correct term?)

```
[
  ['a1', 'b3', 'c2', 'd5']
  ['a1', 'b3', 'c2', 'd6']
  ['a4', 'b3', 'c1', 'd3']

  ...
]
```

I want to filter the list where sum of each sub-list equal to 11

Like

```
[
  ['a1', 'b3', 'c1', 'd6'], // 1+3+1+6 = 11
  ['a4', 'b3', 'c1', 'd3']
  ...
]
```

Please someone help me

Comment: Are the list elements always one letter and one digit? Or could you have `x10`?

Comment: @Bar one letter and on digit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to do it with `sum` and `map`:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [
...   ['a1', 'b3', 'c2', 'd5'],
...   ['a1', 'b3', 'c2', 'd6'],
...   ['a4', 'b3', 'c1', 'd3'],
... ]
>>> [l for l in list_of_lists if sum(map(lambda i: int(i[1]), l)) == 11]
[['a1', 'b3', 'c2', 'd5'], ['a4', 'b3', 'c1', 'd3']]
>>>
```

The `lambda` expression turns a string like `'a4'` into the int `4`, the `map` function applies that lambda to each element of the list, and the comprehension filters the list to only those whose `sum` of the `map` is 11.

Comment: I generally frown upon the use of `map` (or `filter`) with `lambda`. `sum(int(i[1]) for i in l)` is not just shorter and more readable, but understanding comprehensions/generators is more generally useful to the beginner.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be an inplace solution.

```
new_lst = []


for sub_list in lst:
    summ = 0
    for element in sub_list:
        summ += int(element[1])

    if summ == 11:
        new_lst.append(sub_list)
```